# SqlDataReader not returning all rows

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqldatareader

I've made a console application and added a SQL connection.  I need to make sure I'm retrieving all rows from this table.  This is not returning all the rows from the table.  If I execute this query in SSMS, all rows are returned.

```
Dim connString As String = "myconnectionString"
Dim _conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
Dim query As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT first_name FROM Employees", _conn)

_conn.Open()

    Dim recordReader As SqlDataReader = query.ExecuteReader()
    While recordReader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(recordReader.GetValue(0).ToString())
    End While

_conn.Close()
```

When I run this it returns just a seemingly random fraction of the actual amount of rows in the table.

Comment: Have you checked if you're getting an error in the middle? The data reader works connected to database so a connection interruption would cause these symptoms.

Comment: That's a thought.  How would I go about testing that?

Comment: Billy, see if this returns any records: `SELECT first_name FROM Employees WHERE first_name IS NULL;`

Comment: Troy.  Just tried it.  It didn't return anything.

Comment: @KidBilly: you should be seeing an error on the console.

Comment: It could be that your Console window's buffer is too small to keep all the results viewable. If you right-click on the window's title bar, select _Properties_, and open the _Layout_ tab, what number do you see for the _Screen Buffer Size - Height_? If it's too small, you can change it up to 9999.

Comment: Troy.  Duuuude, thank you!  I never even thought about it being something like that.  But that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was returning all of the rows!  The command window had a *buffer size*, so it just wasn't **displaying** all of the rows.

To change the *buffer size*: Right click the top of the command window and go to options.  On the *Layout* tab, set the *buffer size* to something larger.